# Incorrect results from simple `Plot`?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, list-manipulation

I came across this bizarre behaviour whilst noodling around - a change in 'Plot' results...

```
testPlot1 = Plot[Log[HarmonicNumber[n]], 
   {n, 1, 5}]; 
testPlot2 = Plot[Log[HarmonicNumber[n]], 
   {n, 1, 43}]; 
Show[testPlot1, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]
Show[testPlot2, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]
```

The line moves away from the origin, crossing the `n` line increasingly far to the right, and giving no negative output - it just vanishes at the `n` line.

At first I thought it happened exclusively for `n>=43`, but actually, it seems to happen randomly for different domain ranges. Using `Table` gives the correct result.

What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: In the first case, you are not setting `PlotRange` at all, but in `Show` you are using specific `PlotRange`. So why do you expect the results to look the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the plotoption `AxesOrigin->{0,0}`:

```
testPlot1 =Plot[Log[HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}] ;
testPlot2 =Plot[Log[HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, 43}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}] ;

Show[testPlot1, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[testPlot2, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

same plot in both cases!

Comment: Hi @Ulirch. Do you mean `AxesOrigin`? (With an 'e')

Comment: Sorry: Yes  I meant `AxesOrigin`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work.If I specify `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` for `testPlot2`, the curve still hits the `n` line at `n=1` - which is mathematcally incorrect. If I use it for `testPlot1` *and* `testPlot2` the curve still intersects the `n` line in different places for each plot. Mathematica is changing the actual values of the plot, not where the axes are.

Comment: I would expect `Log[HarmonicNumber[1]]==0`

Comment: You're right @Ulrich (and that was what I expected too). I must have entered something wrongly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: increase the `PlotPoints` in `testPlot2`:

```
testPlot1 = Plot[Log[HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, 5}];
testPlot2 = 
  Plot[Log[HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, 43}, PlotPoints -> 100];
Show[testPlot1, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]
Show[testPlot2, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi @Chris. Also good. I have ticked Ulrich's because he got there first, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: No prob -- nothing stops you from upvoting multiple answers BTW :)

Comment: The magic number of PlotPoints must be `>5`, but the option  `PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {1}}]` works to#o!